# Why is this regex from a text file not working with smartmatch?

Tags: regex, perl, smartmatch

I use
[*smartmatch*](https://perlmaven.com/smart-matching-in-perl-5.10)
to check whether a string matches a regex pattern. It stopped working after I decided to store the regex in a text file.

```
my $str   = '123456, some text.';
my $regex = qr/^\d+, some text\.$/;
print "Regex: $regex\n";
```

At this point, the printed regex is `(?^:^\d+, some text\.$)`. I copy-paste it into a file, then I make the code read the file and retrieve the regex, which is stored in `$regexFromFile`.

The following line confirms that `$regex` and `$regexFromFile` are the same, then I proceed to test `$str` against the regex in various ways.

```
print 'Is regex equal to regexFromFile? ' . ($regex eq $regexFromFile) . "\n";

print 'Does str match regex         using =~ ? ' . ($str =~ $regex)         . "\n";
print 'Does str match regexFromFile using =~ ? ' . ($str =~ $regexFromFile) . "\n";
print 'Does str match regex         using ~~ ? ' . ($str ~~ $regex)         . "\n";
print 'Does str match regexFromFile using ~~ ? ' . ($str ~~ $regexFromFile) . "\n";
```

The last line of that code does not behave the same as the previous three lines.

Here is the complete output of the code:

```
Regex: (?^:^\d+, some text\.$)
Is regex equal to regexFromFile? 1
Does str match regex         using =~ ? 1
Does str match regexFromFile using =~ ? 1
Does str match regex         using ~~ ? 1
Does str match regexFromFile using ~~ ?
```

(Note the absence of `1` at the end.)

Edit: To answer a comment, here is how the file is read.

```pl
open(my $FILEHANDLE, 'file.txt') or die "Error: Could not open file.\n";
my @content = <$FILEHANDLE>;
close($FILEHANDLE) or print "Could not close file.\n";
my @content_woEol = ();
foreach my $line (@content){
    $line =~ s/\s*$//;
    push(@content_woEol, $line);
}
my $regexFromFile = $content_woEol[0];
```

Comment: Can you show how you retrieve the `$regexFromFile`?

Comment: Worse, smartmatch is known to be broken. **It's useless to ask why broken code behaves as it does.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `qr//` is actually a **precompiled regular expression**. Copy-pasting the printed regular expression to a file, as you did, then reading it from the file, is not the problem. You would experience the same behavior had you written this line directly in your code:

```
my $regexFromFile = '(?^:^\d+, some text\.$)';
```

If you want to use smatmatch here, I would advise you to do something like the following:

```
my $str   = '123456, some text.';
my $regex = '^\d+, some text\.$';

# Manually store this in the file: ^\d+, some text\.$
# Read $regexFromFile from the file

print 'Does str match regex         using =~ ? ' . ($str =~ /$regex/)         . "\n";
print 'Does str match regexFromFile using =~ ? ' . ($str =~ /$regexFromFile/) . "\n";
print 'Does str match regex         using ~~ ? ' . ($str ~~ /$regex/)         . "\n";
print 'Does str match regexFromFile using ~~ ? ' . ($str ~~ /$regexFromFile/) . "\n";
```

Note the additional `/.../`. Output:

```
Does str match regex         using =~ ? 1
Does str match regexFromFile using =~ ? 1
Does str match regex         using ~~ ? 1
Does str match regexFromFile using ~~ ? 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Smartmatching is broken. Please avoid using it.<sup>[1]</sup>

`$str` is a string, and `$regexFromFile` is a string, so `$str ~~ $regexFromFile` is equivalent to `$str eq $regexFromFile`.

If you wanted `$str ~~ $regexFromFile` to be equivalent to `$str =~ $regexFromFile`, you'd have to convert the misnamed `$regexFromFile` from a string into a regex (e.g. using `qr//`). Of course, the far better solution is to simply use `=~`.

---

1. Many years ago, it was made experimental as a form of deprecation so it could be fixed. Continued use of this broken feature actually prevented a recent effort to fix it.

Comment: Who is downvoting any negative comments about *smartmatching*? From its inception in Perl v5.10 it was a bad idea, and [perldelta v5.10.1](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perldelta.html#Smart-match-changes) started the backslide with `~~` becoming non-commutative, together with consideration of the range operators. It was always a mess, with hope and imagination overruling pragmatism. It was never very Perlish and it has stayed alive for far too long.

Comment: My point is that `$str ~~ $regexFromFile` is not the same as `$str ~~ $regex`, even though `$regexFromFile eq $regex` is true...

Comment: `$regexFromFile eq $regex` compares the stringification of its operands, so `$regexFromFile eq $regex` being true only dictates that `$str ~~ "$regexFromFile"` (false) and `$str ~~ "$regex"` (false) should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

*Smartmatch* has been *experimental* since v5.18 and should never have been used in live production software

It has always required

```
use feature 'switch';
```

And unless you are someone who consciously or explicitly ignores warnings, with

```
no warnings qw/ experimental::smartmatch /;
```

then you will have had ample warning of its demise

You have made an informed choice that was clearly wrong from the start

Comment: @amon: Your comment is confusing people. My post says *"Smartmatch has been experimental since v5.18"*